# Corresponding float in two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have two CSV files.
 
The first one, when seen as a list, looks like this:

```
('Rubus idaeus', '10.0', '56.0')
('Neckera crispa', '9.8785', '56.803')
('Dicranum polysetum', '9.1919', '56.0456')
('Sphagnum subnitens', '9.1826', '56.6367')
('Taxus baccata', '9.61778', '55.68833')
('Sphagnum papillosum', '9.1879', '56.0442')
```

The columns are 'Species','Longitude' and 'Latitude'.
They are observations made in the field.

The other file is also a CSV file. A test made to resemble the real thing. It looks like this:

```
{'y': '58.1', 'x': '22.1', 'temp': '14'}
{'y': '58.2', 'x': '22.2', 'temp': '10'}
{'y': '58.3', 'x': '22.3', 'temp': '1'}
{'y': '58.4', 'x': '22.4', 'temp': '12'}
{'y': '58.5', 'x': '22.5', 'temp': '1'}
{'y': '58.6', 'x': '22.6', 'temp': '6'}
{'y': '58.7', 'x': '22.7', 'temp': '0'}
{'y': '58.8', 'x': '22.8', 'temp': '13'}
{'y': '58.9', 'x': '22.9', 'temp': '7'}
```

Both of the files are very long indeed.

I have the observation, and now I want to find the closest lower number in the file containing climatic data, and then append that line to the other one, so the output becomes:

```
('Dicranum polysetum', '9.1919', '56.0456', 'y': '9.1', 'x': '56.0', 'temp': '7')
```

I tried creating nested loops by iterating through the CSV files using `DictReader`, but it gets very nested very fast. And it will take a tremendous amount of loops to get through the whole thing.
 
Does anybody know of a method?

The code I have at the moment is poor, but I tried looping in several ways and I expect there is something fundamentally wrong with my entire approach.

```
import csv
fil = csv.DictReader(open("TestData.csv"), delimiter=';')
navn = "nyDK_OVER_50M.csv"
occu = csv.DictReader(open(navn), delimiter='\t')

for row in fil:
    print 'x=',row['x']
    for line in occu:
        print round(float(line['decimalLongitude']),1)
        if round(float(line['decimalLongitude']),1) == row['x']:
            print 'You did it, found one dam match'
```

Here's the links for my two files, so you don't have to make up any data in case you know of something that can push me forward.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmstnkq8jl71vcc/nyDK_OVER_50M.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v22j61vi9b43j78/TestData.csv?dl=0

Best regards, 
Mathias

Comment: What are x and y in the climate data? Lat/Lon ?

Comment: Have you looked into storing the data in a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree? This way finding the nearest neighbor is in O(log(n)) time.

Comment: Do you have a temperature for each .1 degree or is your temperature grid missing data? In the former case the problem is trivial.

Comment: I have a temperature for 0.1. It shouldn't be missing any data.

Comment: x and y are lat/long.

Comment: "Very long indeed" - I like your phraseology but linked files are only a few kb; you can just join them in memory.

Comment: Are the files you gave complete? For the temps, we only have data on the line y = x + 36 ; don't you have a grid?

Comment: There are not nearly complete. Unfortunately :)

Comment: If your matrix is sparse and you are trying to determine the temperature for each species, then I would perhaps go for a 2D interpolation of temperatures instead of finding the nearest neighbour. Check out scip.interpolate.interp2d: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Answer (score 1):

Because you say there are no missing temperature data points, then it is much easier to solve the problem:

```
import csv

# temperatures
fil = csv.DictReader(open("TestData.csv"), delimiter=';')
# species
navn = "nyDK_OVER_50M.csv"
occu = csv.DictReader(open(navn), delimiter='\t')

d = {}
for row in fil:
    x = '{:.1f}'.format(float(row['x']))
    y = '{:.1f}'.format(float(row['y']))
    try:
        d[x][y] = row['temp']
    except KeyError:
        d[x] = {y:row['temp']}

for line in occu:
    x = '{:.1f}'.format(round(float(line['decimalLongitude']),1))
    y = '{:.1f}'.format(round(float(line['decimalLatitude']),1))
    temp = d[x][y]
    line['temp'] = temp
    line['x'] = x
    line['y'] = y
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a closer look at it asap. For now it throws me an error on line 21:     temp = d[x][y]
KeyError: '56.0'

Comment: OK, that's because your temperature grid is not complete as you said. It's missing data. Instead look into scikit Nearest Neighbours: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html

Comment: Couldn't it be that it see 56 and 56.0 as two different things? The grid is complete, it has to be :)

Comment: No, because I formatted the strings in the same way; i.e. rounded with one decimal. Perhaps you didn't upload the right data?

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which uses `numpy` to compute the Euclidean distance of each data item to the `x,y` points and joins the item with the data from the `x,y` data tuple with the smallest distance to it.

```
import numpy
import operator

# read the data into numpy arrays
testdata = numpy.genfromtxt('TestData.csv', delimiter=';', names=True)
nyDK     = numpy.genfromtxt('nyDK_OVER_50M.csv', names=True, delimiter='\t',\
                            dtype=[('species','|S64'),\
                                   ('decimalLongitude','float32'),\
                                   ('decimalLatitude','float32')])

# extract the x,y tuples into a numpy array or [(lat,lon), ...]
xy        = numpy.array(map(operator.itemgetter('x', 'y'), testdata))
# this is a function which returns a function which computes the distance
# from an arbitrary point to an origin
distance  = lambda origin: lambda point: numpy.linalg.norm(point-origin)

# methods to extract the (lat, lon) from a nyDK entry
latlon    = operator.itemgetter('decimalLatitude', 'decimalLongitude')
getlatlon = lambda item: numpy.array(latlon(item))

# this will transfrom a single element of the nyDK array into
# a union of it with its closest climate data
def transform(item):
    # compute distance from each x,y point to this item's location
    # and find the position of the minimum
    idx = numpy.argmin( map(distance(getlatlon(item)), xy) )
    # return the union of the item and the closest climate data
    return tuple(list(item)+list(testdata[idx]))

# transform all the entries in the input data set
result = map(transform, nyDK)

print result[0:3]
```

Outputs:

```
[('Rubus idaeus', 10.0, 56.0, 15.0, 51.0, 14.0),
 ('Neckera crispa', 9.8785, 56.803001, 15.300000000000001, 51.299999999999997, 2.0),
 ('Dicranum polysetum', 9.1919003, 56.045601, 14.6, 50.600000000000001, 10.0)]
```

Note: not very close distances but that is probably because there isn't a full grid of `x,y` points in the `.csv` file.